# Reference for the fact that (0=1) implies false requires a universe in MLTT

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, pl.programming-languages, type-theory, dependent-type

It's a fairly well-known fact that deriving a contradiction from a disequality (for example, $(0=1) \to \bot$) in Martin-Loef type theory requires a universe.

The proof is also fairly straightforward -- in the absence of universes, we can erase the dependencies from any dependent type to get a simple type as its shape, and so proving that $(0=1) \to \bot$ implies we can prove $p \to \bot$ for an arbitrary atom $p$, which is of course not possible.

However, I can't find who proved this first! Does anyone have a reference?

Comment: Coquand's "A New Paradox in Type Theory" (94) describes the truth valued semantics of minimal higher-order logic, and seems to suggest that this interpretation was known before. I seem to recall a mention of such a model even for Russell's Type Theory but I can't seem to find it...

Comment: This Martin Hoffman text confirms the Jan Smith reference in the answer, and has a reasonable presentation of that proof with categorical semantics in the exercises https://www.ioc.ee/~james/ITT9200/SyntaxAndSemanticsof%20DependentTypes.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know of:

Jan M. Smith, The independence of Peano's fourth axiom from Martin-Löf's type theory without universes, The Journal of Symbolic Logic 53(3), p. 840-845, 1988.